# Outlook - get email address from Display Name. Works in Python, not C

Tags: c++, c, outlook, com, ole

I am trying to convert some code from Python to C and OLE. The code is getting an email address from the Outlook Display Name.

The Python code works and looks like this:

```
    recipient = self._outlook.Session.CreateRecipient(name)

    recipient.Resolve()

    if self._first:
        print(inspect.getmembers(recipient))
        self._first = False
        print(recipient.Resolved)
        print(recipient.AddressEntry)
        if 'EX' == recipient.AddressEntry.Type:
            exchange_user = recipient.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser()
            email = exchange_user.PrimarySmtpAddress
        elif 'SMTP' == recipient.AddressEntry.Type:
            email = recipient.AddressEntry.Address
        print(email)
```

It, in turn, is basically a python-ized version of the [VBA code on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868500.aspx).

However, in C and OLE I just don't get it and I can only find C#, VBA and C++ with MFC examples (which I am not interested in) on MSDN and other forums, as well as suggestions to use proprietary frameworks.

What I have in C so far. `outlookapp` is successfully initialized with `CoCreateInstance()`.

```
IDispatch *pNS = NULL;
{
    VARIANT x;
    x.vt = VT_BSTR;
    x.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"MAPI");

    VARIANT result;
    VariantInit(&result);
    AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result, outlookapp, L"GetNamespace", 1, x);
    pNS = result.pdispVal;

    SysFreeString(x.bstrVal);
    VariantClear(&x);
}


// Log on by using a dialog box to choose the profile.
{
    VARIANT vtShowDialog;
    vtShowDialog.vt = VT_BOOL;
    vtShowDialog.boolVal = VARIANT_TRUE;
    VARIANT vtNewSession;
    vtNewSession.vt = VT_BOOL;
    vtNewSession.boolVal = VARIANT_TRUE;

    if (FAILED(AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, NULL, pNS, L"Logon", 4, vtNewSession,
        vtShowDialog, vtMissing, vtMissing))) {
        printf("Logon failed.\n"); Sleep(15000); ExitProcess(1);
    }
}

printf("Done logging in to Outlook\n");

IDispatch *recipient = NULL;
{
    VARIANT x;
    x.vt = VT_BSTR;
    x.bstrVal = SysAllocString(L"John Doe");

    VARIANT result;
    VariantInit(&result);
    HRESULT hr = AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result, pNS, L"CreateRecipient", 1, &x);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("Can not CreateRecipient(), error: %x\n", hr); Sleep(60000); ExitProcess(1);
    }
    recipient = result.pdispVal;
}

{
    VARIANT result;
    VariantInit(&result);
    HRESULT hr = AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result, recipient, L"Resolve", 0);
    if (FAILED(hr)) {
        printf("Can not call Resolve()\n");
        Sleep(3000); ExitProcess(1);
    }
}
```

The code dies on the "Can not CreateRecipient()" printf message with the error 0x800706F4 which corresponds to *"A null reference pointer was passed to the stub."*

AutoWrap also writes its own message: `IDispatch::Invoke("CreateRecipient"=0000210a) failed w/err 0x800706f4`

It comes from this code in AutoWrap:

```
// Make the call 
hr = pDisp->Invoke(
    dispID,
    IID_NULL,
    LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,
    autoType,
    &dp,
    pvResult,
    NULL,
    NULL
); 

if (FAILED(hr))  
{ 
    wprintf(L"IDispatch::Invoke(\"%s\"=%08lx) failed w/err 0x%08lx\n",  
        ptName, dispID, hr); 
    return hr; 
}
```

The end objective is to feed address data from Outlook into Excel, and I have Excel automation with OLE already working. Really happy for any ideas - I have really tried to find information about this but not found much on how Outlook actually works on this level.

Comment: @HansPassant would love if you have the time to look briefly at this.

Comment: AutoWrap should return an error code, use the Error Lookup tool in VS to look it up

Comment: @Matt, OK will try that. "A null reference pointer was passed to the stub. " Ouch.

Comment: @Matt, 
0x800706F4 = *A null reference pointer was passed to the stub.*

Comment: You have to debug the AutoWrap function to find out which parameter should not be NULL.  BTW, in native C++, you can call call functions in COM directly, you don't need to use invoke. I found an example regards to execl, not for outlook:  http://www.wilmott.com/messageview.cfm?catid=10&threadid=26137. But the idea is the same.

Comment: I know about not having to use COM directly, but AFAIK I will need exactly the same outlook version on target? Thanks for the link though.

Comment: I'm not sure. As this COM component is Office Interop, not outlook its self. I think MS should maintain compatibility between version of   Office Interop.

Comment: The only value I can ever find back in this repeated Q+A is proof that writing late-bound COM code in C++ is horrible inefficient and error-prone.  It is just a simply typo, `&x` should be `x`.  Please start using the #import directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Passant saw, I just typed `&x` instead of `x` in this line:

```
HRESULT hr = AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result, pNS, L"CreateRecipient", 1, &x);
```

::

```
HRESULT hr = AutoWrap(DISPATCH_METHOD, &result, pNS, L"CreateRecipient", 1, x);
```